# C++ External Declaration Isolation

Tags: c++, namespaces

Consider the following:

```
namespace N {
    extern "C" void f();
}

void g() {
    N::f();
}
```

This code declares an external function with C linkage inside a namespace. This makes possible to refer to such a function from a private namespace, avoiding the resulting namespace pollution caused by an ordinary global external declaration. It also allows client code to issue other (hopefully compatible) declarations for the same function without conflicts, even in the global namespace, possibly originated from a vendor-provided header inclusion.

I often rely on similar constructs in both C and C++ to isolate compilations from bad-written or conflicting header files provided with some libraries. (In C, this is achieved by issuing the needed declarations at function scope, which would be also possible in C++, if not for the `extern` linkage declaration being not allowed at function scope.) This is specially useful for properly linking against a well-defined ABI without having to rely on vendor-provided header files.

**Is it possible to do the same with functions or methods with regular C++ linkage?** That is: to declare an external function with C++ linkage inside a private namespace (or at any sort of local scope), but which possibly refers to a function actually defined inside *another* namespace?

Intended functionality (pseudo-code):

```
namespace N {
    // Actually should link with P::f() (and not N::f()).
    extern "C++" void f();
}

void g() {
    N::f(); // P::f();
}
```

This obviously is not a problem for source files (as opposed to header files), because namespace pollution does not matter in that case. Thus, this question refers mostly to isolating declarations in library header files (for use inside templates and inline functions).

Compiler-specific solutions are welcome (MSVC and GCC being of interest).

**Example:** suppose my library is called `Lib1` and I want to declare everything inside the `Lib1` namespace.

```
// Lib1.hpp
namespace Lib1 {
    class Class1;
    void func1();
    // ...
}
```

Now suppose my library refers to another library, `Lib2`, which is a C library provided by someone else.

```
/* Lib2.h */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct Struct2;
void func2();
/* ... */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In my library, I can refer to entities from `Lib2` without having to include `Lib2.h` at all, if for some reason this is needed:

```
// Lib1.hpp
namespace Lib1 {
    extern "C" void func2();

    inline void inlineX() {
        func2();
    }
}
```

At the same time, a client code is free to include both `Lib1.hpp` and `Lib2.h` (considering it is C++-friendly) without conflicts.

Now, suppose there is a third library, `Lib3`, which is a C++ library and declares entities in the `Lib3` namespace.

```
// Lib3.hpp
namespace Lib3 {
    class Class3;
    void func3();
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to relate to `Lib3` in the same manner as `Lib2`? That is: refer to entities in `Lib3` inside `Lib1.hpp`, without including `Lib3.hpp` but still allowing client code to include both `Lib1.hpp` and `Lib3.hpp` with no hassles?

If, in `Lib1`, it is declared:

```
// Lib1.hpp
namespace Lib3 {
    void func3();
}

namespace Lib1 {
    inline void inlineY() {
        Lib3::func3();
    }
}
```

then it might occur conflicts if client code includes both `Lib1.hpp` and `Lib3.hpp` -- certainly not in this simple example in which the declarations are identical, but subtle differences in real situations can trigger warnings or errors at syntax level, even if the underlying ABI is the same, since this violates the premise of not declaring anything outside the `Lib1` namespace.

Hope this helps to understand the question.

Comment: y not put the implementation of `f` in the source file and not need a namespace in the header?

Comment: also u can use a layer of indirection in case u can't do what i suggested above because they're templates or somn, ie put `void f() { void callMyF(); callMyF(); }` in header and in source put `extern "C" myF(); void callMyF() { return myF(); }`

Comment: It doesn't look like your C linkage example is valid: **7.5/6** ...An entity with C language linkage shall not be declared with the same name as an entity in global scope, unless both declarations denote the same entity...

Comment: Why do you want to write `N` and have it mean `P`? Why not simply write `P`?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the "principle of least astonishment". "extern "C"" only deals with name mangling and doesn't do anything else. So what you're doing is essentially a "black magic" that shouldn't be used in code somebody else will ever read. Code is written for people to read it. So it would be better to just write functition forwarder manually.

Comment: What kind of error are you trying to prevent? Examples please.

Comment: @Kal: As stated I'm looking for a solution which could be used in definitions inside header files. @Igor: Sorry, my example was misleading. `f()` (which now I called `g()`) and `N::f()` were really meant to refer to different entities; the former just illustrates a call to the latter. I've elaborate a hopefully better example. @n.m.: Check the example.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this is what you want or what you wanted to prevent, but the `extern "C"` in the namespace leads to a symbol with C name mangling (without the namespace!). So the protection will only be within your code.

Comment: @Alek and i already gave u one solution in my second comment

Comment: @Kal: Indeed, but that defeats the purpose of inlining in a very silly manner. And even worse, actually _two_ calls are issued -- one at the inline site (to the forwarder function) and one at the forwarder function (to the real API).

Comment: @Alek silly answers to silly questions. also link time optimization can possibly help with inlining, though I don't know all of the optimizations that can be done at link time.

Comment: @Kal: No offense meant by silly, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just the intended usage of the `using` directive in C++?

```
// Lib3.hpp
#pragma once
namespace Lib3 {
    void func3();
}

// Lib1.hpp
#include <Lib3.hpp>
namespace Lib1 {
    using Lib3::func3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, the idea is _not_ having `Lib3::func3()` declared at all -- not inside `Lib3` anyway, but either, _somehow_, at `Lib1`, or at some function (or class) local scope. Let me draw your attention to the C linkage case: albeit `func2()` is _declared inside_ `Lib1`, it refers to something _outside_ `Lib1` -- I wondered if it was possible to do the same with C++-linked entities. However, by looking at the progress of the question, I feel that there is no solution to the problem at the syntax level, but only at the link level, if any (some symbol renaming or the sort).

Comment: In other words, you want the effect of `using`, but then *also* you want to prevent Lib1's users from using Lib3 directly? Sometimes this effect can be achieved with `#define Lib3 __Lib3_internal_to_Lib1 ; #include <Lib3.h> ; #undef Lib3`.

Comment: In fact I want to allow `Lib1`'s users to use `Lib3` directly, however `Lib1` itself is _independent_ from any header file from `Lib3` (and does not declare anything inside the `Lib3` namespace whatsoever). This is what happens in the C case: `Lib1` accesses the C interface, and allows anyone else to include `Lib2.h` at will (because anything `Lib1` declares, which relates to `Lib2`, is inside `Lib1`). So I need to refer to `Lib3` entities with local visibility only (either at local scope or inside the `Lib1` library namespace). Also, the `#define` trick would ensue link errors, wouldn't it?

Comment: I've cleaned up my example to make it clearer what I'm suggesting. What is it about this example that you don't like?

Comment: Your answer is well-directed but it doesn't solve the problem I proposed, because I believe you did not _fully_ understand what I'm looking for. To make things easier to understand, I'll propose a challenge: can you call `Lib3::func3()` _without_ declaring _anything_ inside `Lib3` _and_ without including `Lib3.hpp`? In C, you can: you can declare `func1()`'s prototype at a function local scope and call it. The question is: can you do the same with C++?

Comment: @Alek, no, of course you can't. And while you're right that from a language-lawyer perspective you can do it in C, even in C you can't do it *robustly* from a software-design perspective; if the next version of `Lib3` adds a parameter to `func3` or changes its return type, then your caller will invoke undefined behavior when it tries to call its improperly prototyped `func3`. The only *non-fragile* way to get the declaration of `Lib3::func3` into scope is to #include the header that declares it.

Comment: If you're willing to sacrifice robustness, then you can do it via unwarranted chumminess with the implementation: `namespace Lib1 { void func3() __asm__("__ZN4Lib35func3Ev"); }`. This is as fragile as the C solution, in that it will break if `Lib3`'s implementation changes. (It may also break if you switch compilers.)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Language-wise, there is no "robustness" in either approach -- I made clear in the question that I'm dealing with problematic header files and with _stable_ binary interfaces. There is no "next version" to worry about, or not something that will change behind by back anyway. And ultimately every aspect of linking is implementation-defined, so non-fragility is an unwarranted fiction. But putting the rant aside, which would lead us into long and unnecessary digressions, your last example is actually quite appreciable -- at least shows _one way_ of dealing with this.